# Having problems reading from a DB

Tags: php, android, database, sqlite

I am programming an assignment and I need to figure out how to read a database file that Is created using a PHP script I have coded. I am new to the Android platform and have spent hours in the past week following tutorials but am still struggling. I need to read from the database and display in a UI on the screen. I’m sure it can’t be too difficult but I’m slipping up somewhere! Any help would be truly appreciated.

Current PHP Script-

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
//Connect to college database
$studentnum = "SY090627";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","******","*******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("computin_mobile", $con);
//Select all needed student data
//Must include custext from student table to retrive students college username
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students, time WHERE (time.CusText5='$studentnum' AND students.StuRef ='$studentnum') ORDER BY time.DayNum ASC, time.StartTime");



$newLine = "\n";

try
{
  //create the database
  $database = new SQLiteDatabase('myDatabase.sqlite', 0666, $error);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  die($error);
}

//add Lesson table to database
$query = 'CREATE TABLE Lessons ' .
         '(Day TEXT, StartTime TEXT, EndTime TEXT, Teacher TEXT, Description TEXT, Room TEXT)';

if(!$database->queryExec($query, $error))
{
  die($error);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
//insert data into database
$dayr = $row['Day'];
$query =
  'INSERT INTO Lessons (Day, StartTime, EndTime, Teacher, Description, Room) ' .
  'VALUES ("'.$row['Day'].'", "'.$row['StartTime'].'", "'.$row['EndTime'].'", "'.$row['Teacher'].'", "'.$row['Description'].'", "'.$row['Room'].'")';

if(!$database->queryExec($query, $error))
{
  die($error);
}
  }
//read data from database
$query = "SELECT * FROM Lessons";
if($result = $database->query($query, SQLITE_BOTH, $error))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch())
  {
    print("Day: {$row['Day']} <br />" .
          "Start Time: {$row['StartTime']} <br />".
          "End Time: {$row['EndTime']} <br />".
          "Teacher: {$row['Teacher']} <br />".
          "Description {$row['Description']} <br />".
          "Room: {$row['Room']} <br /><br />");

  }
}
else
{
  die($error);
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nick: I hope, that you had created a webpage using php and instered that data's in mysql using php, your need is you want to show that web page in android, and if you modified those in andorid UI, that modifications, has to be stored in mysql db, am i right???, is this your need????

Comment: @SankarGanesh, thanks for your speedy reply. My PHP page takes data from a MySQL database and passes it to my appliaction in.sqlite format for android.

Comment: @Nick: ok, then what's your problem, can explain it in detail, manner, so that i can help you buddy

Comment: @SankarGanesh, I haven’t been able to get any tutorials working, I am completely stuck! Is there any places or tutorials you could point me too? I’ve had a go at adapting a couple tutorials to my needs and they compile without error but crash at runtime with no errors. I’m stuck! Apologies for such a broad question!

Comment: @Nick: No problem, now tell me , buddy, i had assumed that , you had worte that php page , now tell me, did you parsed that php page and displayed in android, successfully, pls replay quick???

Comment: your php script gets data from MySQL and passes to Android as SQLite? How? Your php script should give the data to your Android in JSON or XML format. To be precise, your Android app should "get the data from" php script as JSON or XML or any other format which is not SQLite

Comment: @SankarGanesh, I have written the PHP script but im not sure how well it works. It does create a SQLite DB which is readable in PHP but im not sure if Android likes it. Currently the Android app was going to request this php file from a remote server. @Sarwar Erfan  I looked into passing it a JSON format, and was tempted by XML but struggled to follow documentation. Do you think it would be best to do it via this method?

Comment: @Nick: Unless you show some code or give more information, there is little chance we can help. Edit your question and add more info.

Comment: @NetCode, as suggested I have added my PHP code. Android wise I currently don’t have anything as the tutorials I followed crashed. I’m really looking for the best approach to do this. Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: @Nick: Create a Xml format for that php and parse that url using SAX parser in Android and receive the value from android and handle it in your php page and store it in the MySQL DB?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create the  mysql to xml using php
For that refer see these url [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-query2xml/), [this](http://www.kirupa.com/web/mysql_xml_php.htm)  and [this](http://www.codediesel.com/php/converting-mysql-queries-to-xml/).
  Step2: Once , you had created the XML file, then parse that xml file using SAX parser, For these Refer see this [url](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)